# setTimeout is not waiting before changing the DOM

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to change some classes after a specific time with **setTimeout**, but all I get is instant change without waiting 2 seconds as wanted. What I'm doing wrong?

here is the JS

```
function addElements() {
    var data = ["empty","typeA","typeB","typeC"];
    for(var k=0;k<data.length;k++) {
    var set=document.getElementById("empty");
        set.setAttribute("id", "empty"+k);
        if(data[k] !== "empty") {
            var s = set.setAttribute("class", data[k]);
            setTimeout(function() { s; }, 2000);
        }
        else set.setAttribute("class", data[k]);
}
}
```

and HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="addElements()">Start</a>
<div id="empty" class="empty"></div>
<div id="empty" class="empty"></div>
<div id="empty" class="empty"></div>
<div id="empty" class="empty"></div>
```

corrected JS in case someone will need it by mistake

```
function addElements() {
    var time = 0;
    var data = ["empty","typeA","typeB","typeC"];
    for(var k=0;k<data.length;k++) {
        var set=document.getElementById("empty");
        set.setAttribute("id", "empty"+k);
        var cName = data[k];

        if(cName  !== "empty") {
            time += 2000;
            (function(set, cName ) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    set.setAttribute("class", cName );
                }, time);
            })(set, cName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to get around the scoping issue with `k`

```
var cName = data[k];
if(cName  !== "empty") {
    (function(set, cName ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            set.setAttribute("class", cName );
        }, 2000);
    })(set, cName);
}
```

Comment: well, now I no longer get an undefined value, but after 2 seconds is changing the last div class, even thought in console cName seems to get all values after the first 2 seconds

Comment: whoops, need to pass in set too.

Comment: ok, now the only problem left is that it changes everything after first 2 seconds and don't wait 2 seconds each time cName !== "empty"

Comment: well you got an if statement outside of the timeout, is that the problem?

Comment: well, that if should check each time cName is different than empty and wait 2 seconds before changing the class for each different value, but seems like it works only once, after that doesn't wait anymore those 2 seconds

Comment: Well that is not going to happen with this code, that is going to require totally different logic.

Comment: thank you. all I had to do it add a variable timer += 2000 and use it instead of that delay

Answer (score 3):

When you do `var s = set.setAttribute("class", data[k]);`, you are running the `setAttribute` function.   Thus, you are setting the attribute, then setting `s` to the return value, which is `undefined`.

Doing `s;` does nothing.  That's why `setTimeout(function() { s; }, 2000);` doesn't actually do anything.

What you want to do is run the function *inside* `setTimeout`.  Also, since this will run after the loop is done, you need to save a reference to `k` by making a closure.

```
var timeoutFunction = function(set, k){
    return function(){
        set.setAttribute("class", data[k]);
    }
};
setTimeout(timeoutFunction(set, k), 2000);
```

Comment: actually your answer is wrong since `k` will not be what you expect! `k` will be equal to `data.length` when the setTimeout runs!

Comment: I added that var s because the way you say I get an undefined value in console and is not changing the class

Comment: @epascarello: Oh!  Whoops!  Let me fix that.

Comment: @user2035693: Try it now, I had a small mistake! :)

Comment: thank you. for some reason @epascarello answer worked better with the changes that I had to do.